# Reference for Taylor's Theorem and Calculus II

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I am currently studying a course *Real Analysis II*(or *Calculus II*).

My Instructor gave me the reference to *M. Spivak, Calculus on manifolds, fifth edition, Westview Press, 1971*

But I find this has a very low number of examples and proofs are very concise and some of the topics are missing as per the course contents.

> Can anyone please recommend me some good references for the following Contents(Specifically for Taylor's Theorem):

Vector-valued functions, continuity, linear transformations, differentiation, total derivative, chain rule, *Taylor's Theorem for scalar and vector fields*.

Determinants, Jacobian, implicit function theorem, inverse function theorem, rank theorem

Partition of unity, Derivatives of higher-order

Riemann integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$, differentiation of integrals, change of variables, Fubini’s theorem.

Exterior algebra, simplices, chains of simplices, Stokes theorem, vector fields, Divergence of a vector field, Divergence theorem, closed and exact forms, Poincare lemma

Comment: I like personally [Analysis by Zorich](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/3662489910/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i0). It is suitable for university students in math.

Comment: Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus is a book I found very useful for understanding many of the topics you listed. It's at times tough, but VERY clearly written and very rewarding. I used it simultaneously with Spivak and I found it to be a good combination. Also, it's available freely online:)

Comment: Susan Colley's "Vector Calculus" worked well for me. She delves into the many of the above topics you have listed with an emphasis on linear algebra which makes many of the formulae a lot cleaner. The last chapter is on exterior algebra/calculus (up to the generalized stokes theorem). This chapter is a nice introduction, but I would look elsewhere for a more complete examination of that topic specifically.

Comment: Look at [**Advanced Calculus of Several Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486683362) by C. H. Edwards (very good for multivariable Taylor theorem matters, especially if you have a weak background and need a lot more about the topic than in standard multivariable calculus texts) and [**Functions of Several Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387902066) by Wendell Fleming (slightly more advanced than Edwards; has a lot more regarding the topics in your last sentence). Loomis and Sternberg's **Advanced Calculus** that @peek-a-boo mentioned might be even better, IF you can handle it.